# SSH git keys and know_hosts

Tags: git, ssh, circleci

I'm experiencing something strange, I'm working with CircleCI for automation of deployments. I've added the private key for automate acces for deploy, when one ssh to the server it get into; but when I do a git push to the ssh://... it shows that need the password.

Can be possible to see which keys use git for this, and why ssh works but git itself don't?

EDIT

If I dump the known_hosts

```
ssh-keygen -H -F $stli
```

Host 167.99.150.251 found: line 9 type ED25519
|1|sensitive
Host 167.99.150.251 found: line 10 type RSA
|1|sensitive
Host 167.99.150.251 found: line 11 type ECDSA
|1|sensitive
Host 167.99.150.251 found: line 12 type ED25519
|1|sensitive
Host 167.99.150.251 found: line 13 type RSA
|1|sensitive
Host 167.99.150.251 found: line 14 type ECDSA
|1|sensitive

Even...

```
sudo git push test test
```

The authenticity of host '167.99.150.251 (167.99.150.251)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 77:4c:36:0a:0b:bb:c2:8b:45:64:c1:50:24:ed:5b:b9.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? Step was canceled

And ssh'ing...

```
ssh -vvv $stlu@$stli

OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016

debug1: Reading configuration data /home/circleci/.ssh/config

debug1: /home/circleci/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to 167.99.150.251 [167.99.150.251] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa_fa380aa18a6ed85ac0abc9b0e32ae863 type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa_fa380aa18a6ed85ac0abc9b0e32ae863-cert type -1

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4

debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000

debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "167.99.150.251" from file "/home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts"

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ED25519 in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:9

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:10

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:11

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:12

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:13

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ED25519 in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:14

debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 6 keys

debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 

debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com

debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none

debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com

debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none

debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 77:4c:36:0a:0b:bb:c2:8b:45:64:c1:50:24:ed:5b:b9

debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "167.99.150.251" from file "/home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts"

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ED25519 in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:9

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:10

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:11

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:12

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:13

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ED25519 in file /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:14

debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 6 keys

debug1: Host '167.99.150.251' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.

debug1: Found key in /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:11

debug2: kex_derive_keys

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent

debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug2: key:  (0x55a1b7443680),

debug2: key:  (0x55a1b74434e0),

debug2: key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa_fa380aa18a6ed85ac0abc9b0e32ae863 ((nil)), explicit

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password

debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password

debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey

debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password

debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Offering RSA public key: 

debug3: send_pubkey_test

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

debug1: Offering RSA public key: 

debug3: send_pubkey_test

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279

debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp fa:38:0a:a1:8a:6e:d8:5a:c0:ab:c9:b0:e3:2a:e8:63

debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA fa:38:0a:a1:8a:6e:d8:5a:c0:ab:c9:b0:e3:2a:e8:63

debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).

Authenticated to 167.99.150.251 ([167.99.150.251]:22).

debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]

debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0

debug2: channel 0: send open

debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com

debug1: Entering interactive session.

debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_JOB_ID
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
debug3: Ignored env NODE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env stlu
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_NODE_TOTAL
debug3: Ignored env stlfp
debug3: Ignored env r1
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_INTERNAL_SCRATCH
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_UPSTREAM_JOB_IDS
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_INTERNAL_TASK_DATA
debug3: Ignored env NO_PROXY
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_COMPARE_URL
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_BRANCH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env stli
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_JOB
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_WORKING_DIRECTORY
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_WORKSPACE_ID
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_PREVIOUS_BUILD_NUM
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env rdu
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_STAGE
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_BUILD_URL
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLECI
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env YARN_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_SHA1
debug3: Ignored env CI
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_REPOSITORY_URL
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_INTERNAL_CONFIG
debug3: Ignored env BASH_ENV
debug3: Ignored env rde
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_SHELL_ENV
debug3: Ignored env DEBIAN_FRONTEND
debug3: Ignored env pr1
debug3: Ignored env CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-34-generic x86_64) ...
```

Comment: It is virtually impossible to diagnose the problem based on the information provided

Comment: Maybe the ssh connection is using a different user name in the two cases. As @MadPhysicist says, it's impossible to tell with the information you've given us. Show us, in the question, the actual commands you're typing. (Obviously don't show us any private keys.)

Comment: I think for starters it would be enough to see the output without the `-vvv`. (And format the output as code, please.)

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` for the `git push` command? What does `git config remote.origin.url` say?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm using it because the folder is created with a different user as owner. I'm not pushing to origin, actually.

Comment: Again, what does `git config remote.origin.url` say?